# filter an array and get invalid items in php

Tags: php, arrays, validation

I have an array of phone numbers, and I need a **fast way** to split this array into **valid** and **invalid** phone numbers (according to my definition of valid and invalid), something like:

```
$phone_numbers = array(
    '04165555555',
    '02125555555'
);

$valid_phone_number_regex = '/^0?(416|426|412|424|414)(\d{7})$/i';
```

I could use `array_filter` to get all of the valid numbers, but I also need the invalid ones (for reporting issues)
in a fast way, the array may hold **thousands** of numbers!

Comment: ...add `array_diff()` and you have the invalid ones.

Comment: If you're performing operations on thousands of rows, you may want to consider doing it in a database as it's optimised for that sort of thing. Failing that, I think your `array_filter` approach is about the best bet with `array_diff` for invalids

Comment: what's wrong with array_filter() to get $valids followed by an array_diff() against the original array and $valids to get the invalid numbers

Comment: @MarkBaker: there's nothing wrong with that, the only wrong is that didn't occurre to me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you get the valid ones from [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter), use [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/array_diff) to return all of the elements from the `$input_array` that are not in the `$working` array.

```
$input_array = array( '04165555555', '02125555555');
$working = array_filter( $input_array, function( $el){ return preg_match( '/^0?(416|426|412|424|414)(\d{7})$/i', $el ); });
$not_working = array_diff( $input_array, $working);
```

**Output:**

```
Valid:
array(1) { [0]=> string(11) "04165555555" }
Invalid:
array(1) { [1]=> string(11) "02125555555" }
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/fnx2S3)